# Validation error message with exclamation icon in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an MVC 5 view design where I need error messages to be displayed with exclamation icon/image before, like
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1Jiz.png)

Is it possible to do with @Html.ValidationMessageFor() validation messages,to show with exclamation icon/image(**responsive**)?

I tried adding glyphicon before validation message,

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control text-line", @placeholder = "Email Id *" })
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign colorRed"></i>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Question:
1. Implementing like above, always shows the exclamation glyphicon, I need it to be displayed only when validation error occurs.
2. Is there any other way of using scripts or styles for achieving this, with custom icon images?

Comment: `ValidationMessageFor()` adds `class="field-validation-error"` if the property value is invalid. You could use some css with pseudo selectors - `.field-validation-error:before { ...` to generate the icon so it only appears when there is an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css for add background image to your  error message

```
.text-danger{
 background-image: url('dangerimg.png');
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

if you want add character before error message you can use

```
 .text-danger::before {
     content:'!';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.field-validation-error:before {
content: url('../images/image.png');
}
```

This worked to display image only when error occurs as said by [Stephen Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke)

```
.text-danger{
 content: url('../images/image.png');
}
```

.text-danger class display the image even if there is no error.